# Re-map right click from [shift-F10] to [shift-F9] on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping, right-click

<kbd>shift-F10</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut for right clicking. I'd like to change it to F9, because that is easier to find on the keyboard without looking. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I think [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) should be able to help you do this.
Create a script, and add the following:

```
+{F9}::
Send +{F10}
return
```